# Finding Gmail Snooze dates in API

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

Is it possible to access the date of a Gmail snooze through the API? I came accross a hack in stackoverflow that allows users to search for which emails are snoozed via a secret label search “label:snoozed”, but lables dont normally have an associated date, especially one that will return to the inbox in the future.

Im trying to create a web routine that syncs a todo list with emails and want to the due date to automatically update with when the snoozed email will re-appear.

Is this possible with any API or developer resources google offers?

Comment: I am really looking for this feature, too, for the same use case. Did you find any way? Did you try programatically adding the label "snoozed" to see what this does?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can’t retrieve the date of a Gmail snooze using the API. 
There is a Feature Request already reported for this behavior on Issue tracker:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/109952618

At the moment you can only list them and retrieve the messages that has this label ‘snoozed’ active on them:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q=label%3Asnoozed
```